# Destroy Object in X++

Tags: x++

How to destroy an object in x++ ?

Comment: Maybe this is usefull: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa886274.aspx , objects are automatically destroyed when there are no more references to the object.

Comment: @Kevin - that should be an answer, not a comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects are automatically destroyed when there are no more references to the object.

This means that if we have a `object a` and `object b` and `b` holds a reference to `a`, `a` will not be collected as long as `b` holds a reference to `a`.

If the reference between `a` and `b` would be removed `a` would become eligible for garbage collection, and thus `a` will be destroyed in a later stage.

You might want to check out this link: [destructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa886274.aspx).